# Align span elements side by side

Tags: css

I have placed three span elements side by side inside a div. Third span element contains text i have added word-break css property so that if the text exceeds width the text breaks. Now how can i apply margin to the text which is in next line to align with above lines.

```
<div class="legend_data" style="line-height:18px;word-break:break-word">
  <span class="legend_text" style="float: left;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="test">
  </span>
  <span style="background-color:#32CD32;float: left;width: 12px;
   height: 12px;"></span>
  <span class="legend_text" style="margin-left: 1%;"> sample text  sample  text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text
  </span>
</div>
```

[image]

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ssp/9r5mbwey/1/)

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code. I’m not sure what you’re trying to do. Why do you need those two `span`s at the beginning? Why not simply setting a `padding-left` to the containing box?

Comment: Are those `span`s icons or something like that?

Comment: Please clarify what the purpose of the second span is. What is the possible content of it? What size can it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of restructuring might get you on your way.

Firstly, move `<span class="legend_text" style="float: left;">...</span>` and `<span style="background-color:#32CD32;float: left;width: 12px;
   height: 12px;"></span>` in a separate container div and float it to the left, like below:

```
<div class="legend_data_controls">
    <input type="checkbox" value="test">
    <span class="legend_text_box"></span>
</div>
```

Then set `overflow:hidden` on parent element to [clear floats](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

```
.legend_data {
    line-height: 18px;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And that should be it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="legend_data">
    <div class="legend_data_controls">
        <input type="checkbox" value="test">
        <span class="legend_text_box"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="legend_data_content">
        <span> sample text  sample  text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text
        </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.legend_data {
    line-height: 18px;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.legend_data_controls {
    float: left;
}

.legend_data_controls input {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.legend_text_box {
    background-color:#32CD32;
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.legend_data_content {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

**[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/c3u7u9qa/)**

Hope that helps